# alternate two li without hide, toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

With  hide and toggle this script works well but I dont like the movement of links because the hidden li I'd like use detach() or something similar what exactly replace the two links.
Thanks

**Edit**:
when you click on Show conversations, Hide conversation appears slightly to the right because the hidden li.
I can not change the css because the menu is dinamically generated also with other content

```js
     $("a[href='hide']").hide();
   $("a[href='show'], a[href='hide']").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("a[href='show'], a[href='hide']").toggle();
 });
```

```css
#menu {
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: 97%;
background-color: #bab3d6;
height: 20px;
line-height: 18px;
}

#menu ul {
padding-left: 10px;
border: 0 none;
margin: 0;
}
#menu li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="show">Show conversations</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="hide">Hide conversations</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify *"I dont like the movement of links"*? You could toggle the hidden state of the `li`s instead of the links.

Comment: when you click on Show conversations, Hide conversation appears slightly to the right because the hidden li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you are selecting the `a` tag in jQuery rather than the `li` tag.  I added a `.parent` to select the `li`.  If you don't want to do it this way, you can simply remove the `margin-left` where you style `li`.

### Alternatively

You could  simply add id's to your `li`'s and make those clickable.  It would result in much cleaner code.

```js
$("a[href='hide']").parent().hide();
   $("a[href='show'], a[href='hide']").parent().on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("a[href='show'], a[href='hide']").parent().toggle();
 });
```

```css
#menu {
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: 97%;
background-color: #bab3d6;
height: 20px;
line-height: 18px;
}

#menu ul {
border: 0 none;
margin: 0;
padding-left:5px;
}
#menu li {
margin-left: 10px;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="show">Show conversations</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="hide">Hide conversations</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just toggle the `li` instead of the `a` link? No need for css changes.

Comment: Dang, smart.  Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `display:inline-block` for the list elements you could float them left and remove the list styling like:

```js
$("a[href='hide']").hide();
$("a[href='show'], a[href='hide']").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("a[href='show'], a[href='hide']").toggle();
});
```

```css
#menu {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 97%;
  background-color: #bab3d6;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#menu ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 0 none;
  margin: 0;
  list-style:none;
}

#menu li {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="show">Show conversations</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="hide">Hide conversations</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```